# I think "The man who I thought was thoroughly honest proved to be a swindler" is acceptable. But my book says the answer should be "whom"

Tags: speech

I got this question from a book. In opinion both whom and who sounds correct. The Question is. "The man whom i thought was thoroughly honest proved to be a swindler." 
But my book says the answer should be "whom".

Answer (score 1):

*Whom* is incorrect in this case. You can turn your statement into a question as such:

> Who did you think was thoroughly honest but proved to be a swindler?
>
> Answer: I thought **he** (the man) was.

You would never say:

> I thought **him** was.

By the way, in modern English, you can always use *who* instead of *whom*. *Whom* has been falling out of favor for a long time. You’ll scarcely hear it in casual conversation, and even in formal contexts, *who* is widely accepted. It’s better to use *who* when you could’ve used *whom* than vice versa. Being wrong while trying to enforce a prescriptive rule will always garner heaps of ridicule.