# Who or whom? "I wanted you to listen to this interview by an author who(m?) many of you read"

Tags: grammar, whom

Which word should I be using in the following sentence: "I wanted you to listen to this interview by an author who(m?) many of you already read". Who or whom?

I saw this answer [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly), but who/whom in this case cannot be replaced by neither "he" nor "him", so I'm still unsure.

Please advise.

Comment: You can go for "I wanted you to listen to this interview by an author who is already read by many of you" instead.

Comment: who or whom? How do you know?

Comment: 1)I wanted you to listen to this interview by an author .  2) Many of you have already read him/her.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich "I wanted you to listen to this interview by an author whom is already by many of you" is grammatically incorrect and sounds wrong.

Comment: I would say 'who', or maybe "an author 'that' many of you 'have' already read."

Comment: 'He' (not 'Him') is an author who many of you already read...

Comment: At the question you mention,  'One need never use whom, and if one is even a little bit dubious about a situation, one should certainly not use whom there. That's the rule. The simple rule. If you insist on zombie rules, be aware you're late to the game, and there are lots more zombie rules out there already. Whom has kicked the bucket, shuffled off this mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the bleedin' choir invisible. This is an ex-pronoun. Let it lie in peace. (John Lawler)' is clear.

Comment: I would say 'whom', but I'd be glad it was followed by 'many' as I'd be able to make the consecutive m's sound almost like a single one and leave my listeners unsure which word I had gone for.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Dead Parrot sketch?

Comment: @Rattler It would be a great coincidence if it were not. // This has certainly been covered here before, but I'm having difficulty tracking down the precise duplicate. Here, 'whom' would have been the only answer allowed in grammar schools in the UK 50 years ago, but 'who' has replaced it in almost all usages (but not _directly_ after a preposition: 'For Whom the Bell Tolls') nowadays. 'Whom' is acceptable, but on the rarefied side of formal. Most people would choose 'who', and people arguing against this are over-prescriptive. 'Whose work' avoids the issue entirely.

Comment: I believe that in British English, 'whom' in this case (objective pronoun), is perfectly acceptable and has a formal touch.  Nowadays, it's rarely used though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No problemo. I thought they wanted the traditional pedantry, but I agree that "whom" is pretty much defunct.

Comment: Ah; this question is clearly the same: [I think "The man who I thought was thoroughly honest proved to be a swindler" is acceptable. But my book says the answer should be "whom".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424253/why-whom-instead-of-who) (though some think that this was itself a duplicate).

Comment: You read the wrong answer. The much better answer to that question states the real solution: **Don't use _whom_**. _Who_ is correct in this sentence, and every sentence. So is _that_, ditto, and so is nothing at all, like most relative clauses: _by an author many of you read_. Anyway, if you're ever in doubt about its use, don't ever use it.

Comment: In addition to picking the wrong rule, you're not using the rule correctly. In "many of you already read X", X should be "him" not "he", so per that rule you should use "whom". (But in normal English usage, "who" is now universal.)

Comment: Teaching kids the proper use of *whom* is similar to teaching them how to dial a rotary phone. Sure, they may want to recognized them when they occasionally come across one or in an old movie, but they don't need to know how to use one themselves.

Comment: Only time I use whom is when it is a dative. And that is not really necessary, just a product of having studied German.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In formal, written English, *whom* is correct here:

> *I wanted you to listen to this interview by an author whom many of you already read.*

In the answer you referred to (*The easy way to tell which is technically correct is to substitute he and him for who and whom, then rearrange the word order to see which sounds right.*), it looks like you skipped the part about rearranging. Substitute first, then rearrange:

> *who many of you already read* --> *he many of you already read* --> *many of you already read he*
>
> *whom many of you already read* --> *him many of you already read* --> *many of you already read him*

What's tricky in these constructions is that *whom* is an object but it comes before the subject.

Some have declared *whom* to be dead, but it isn't—not yet:

> However, if you are writing at work, at college or university, or for
> publication, it is acceptable and even advisable to use the more
> formal *whom,* especially in constructions with a preposition.
> <sub>Source: [Lexico: "Who" Or
> "Whom"?](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043658/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/who-or-whom)</sub>

In spoken or informal English (as your example utterance is), the rule can be relaxed, and indeed, is better dismissed altogether if you want to sound normal.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer, acknowledging the various voices heard in the discussion.

Comment: I still would use ‘whom’ unless I wanted to sound like a numpty.  It’s like - we hide our use of proper English - so we can sound like ‘everyone else’ - ie those who do not know to use it properly. Then the whole thing gets downgraded and we all end up sounding like obs. lol and imho! And, with less examples of ‘proper English’ being used - less and less people hear it as an example - and so it gets even worse!

Comment: If the expected answers are, say, ME, US, YOU (Obj.), HIM, HER (obj.), THEM, their questions will be WHOM. If the above are, say, I, WE, YOU, HE, SHE, THEY, their questions will be WHO.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted you to listen to this interview by an author **whom** many of you
>   already read.

Have you read this author?

Have you really read ***him***?

Comment: I'm picking yours as the correct answer, even though many have made convincing cases for "who". However, none of them wrote an "official" answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich: There have been many convincing cases in favor of the phlogiston theory, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the construction slightly:  “I wanted to listen ... with whom many of you may already be acquainted.”

Comment: This would be improved by saying why this construction is better.